# PostgreSQL: no native scripting and transactions?

Tags: postgresql, scripting, transactions

Sorry for potential FAQ, RTFM, etc. If I understand correctly, transactions could not be used in native scripting units (functions, including anonymous do-blocks). What would PostgreSQL guys recommend as the least "not natural" way to combine scripting and transactions?

Comment: Are you committed to running multiple transactions "inside" the database and if so, why?

Comment: @RichardHuxton No, just to save chunks of progress.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about *autonomous transactions*.

If so, you are correct that PostgreSQL doesn't support true stored procedures with autonomous transactions yet. (Feel free to sponsor work or contribute time...)

Your options are:

- Use dblink to make connections-to-self and do the discrete units of work that way
- Use an external process that connects to Pg
- Use an in-db script with pl/python, pl/perl, etc that connects to the DB using psycopg2 / DBD::Pg / etc, rather than using the SPI, and does the work that way. Essentially you code the script like an externally connecting script, but run it within the DB for convenience.